# How to output a CW tone or a Broadband Noise in GnuRadio?

Tags: software-defined-radio, gnuradio

Kindly, can anyone show me how to output CW tone or a Broadband Noise in GnuRadio in a sort of simple flowgraph if possible?

Update:

So, what I did is I tried not to overthink the whole issue here and followed @Kevin's advice and came up with two simple CW tone flowgraph and another simple Broadband Noise flowgraph (as seen below).

CW_Tone Flowgraph:

[image]

Broadband_Noise Flowgraph:

[image]

My question now, if you think that these are legit CW tone and Broadband Noise flowgraphs, what should I do to make them transmit the generated signals? Just connect the UHD-USRP Sink block to the output?

Comment: I would appreciate if you accompany your down vote with a reasoning so that I avoid any similar inconvenience in future questions.

Comment: I would say that this question shows insufficient research effort or context. If you're not sure how to set up a flow graph, read the manual and then explain where you weren't able to understand it or proceed. If you're not sure which block(s) you should use, write down how you've looked. Finally, when you say "output", what do you want to output it _to_? **Questions that explain where you are so far, not just what you want, are not only a sign of doing your part of the work, but also are easier to answer, because we can tell which parts need to be explained.**

Comment: @KevinReidAG6YO, Sorry about! Your recommendation are absolutely worth to be followed. I will do my best and update my question. Sorry again!

Comment: Thank you, I look forward to seeing your edit. I would also recommend — now that I have seen [your other question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/15086/a-gnuradio-program-that-can-output-some-arbitrary-waveform-read-from-a-file-cont) — avoiding posting additional similar questions before you have gotten any reactions to the first one. Instead, post one of them, and use what you learned to ask the second question more precisely.

Comment: @KevinReidAG6YO, I will. Thanks Kevin.

Comment: @KevinReidAG6YO, please, take a look at my updated posting at your convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what should I do to make them transmit the generated signals? Just connect the UHD-USRP Sink block to the output?

You need to do that, but there are a couple more points:

- Make sure that you **remove the throttle block.** Using a throttle as well as a hardware device sink (whether USRP or audio) will potentially cause stuttering. The rule is that you should ideally have only one block that "has a clock" in the flow graph: in your case the clock will be the USRP because it decides how fast it wants to consume the samples based on its DAC clocking.
- **You must change the sample rate** from 32 kHz to a sample rate that is supported by the USRP — probably a higher one. Read the documentation for your specific USRP model to find out what is supported.

Comment: Great! Thanks a LOT Kevin.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transmit Morse code, or just to learn more about flowgraphs, you might be interested in https://github.com/duggabe/gr-morse-code-gen

Note: if you change the output rate to something other than 48khz, you will need to change the parameter calculations as well.