# A gnuradio program that can output some arbitrary waveform read from a file containing I/Q values

Tags: software-defined-radio, gnuradio

I am trying to figure out how to create a gnuradio program that can output some arbitrary waveform read from a file containing I/Q values. 
I would highly appreciate any guidance in this topic. Simple example would be a great help for a beginner like me.

Comment: Since we are all unpaid volunteers here and our time is limited, it is expected that users will do a reasonable amount of research before asking a question here. Please see [How do I ask a good question](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: @MikeWaters, I apologize for any inconvenience here. I did a lot of research about this topic before I post it here! I just couldn't see any online helpful topics that guide a beginner like me to penetrate this topic. I totally got lost while doing my research, literally felt lost. Thats why my question came out in such poor format, probably!

Comment: The [Official Guided GNU Radio tutorials](https://tutorials.gnuradio.org) do cover this.